# setText wont work in the thread

Tags: android, multithreading

Hi i have this code to modify a text view but it keeps telling me : **Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**
here is my code :

```
public void Simulation()
{
    ambientTemp = 20;
    engTemp = 20;
    mileage = 123456;
    fuel = 100;

    thread = new Thread()
    {
        menu1_Fragment f1 = new menu1_Fragment();
        menu2_Fragment f2 = new menu2_Fragment();
        menu3_Fragment f3 = new menu3_Fragment();

        public void run()
        {
            for (int i=0; i<l; i++)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(99);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                speed = SPEED[i];
                revs = ENGSPEED[i];
                System.out.println(speed);
                System.out.println(revs);
                    fuel -= 1;
                    System.out.println(fuel);
                    engTemp += 0.5;
                    System.out.println(engTemp);
                    mileage += 1;
                    System.out.println(mileage);

                    ...
                    View item2 = findViewById(R.id.milage);
                   // f1.setMileage(item2,mileage);
                    View item3 = findViewById(R.id.ambienttemp);
                    f1.setAmbientTemp(item3,ambientTemp);
                    View item4 = findViewById(R.id.gear);
                    f1.setGear(item4,gear);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.container, f1);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
```

**f1.setMileage(item2,mileage);** this one is causing the probleme ... how can i fix it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put all your codes related to a view inside a ui thread

```
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                      View item2 = findViewById(R.id.milage);
               // f1.setMileage(item2,mileage);
                View item3 = findViewById(R.id.ambienttemp);
                f1.setAmbientTemp(item3,ambientTemp);
                View item4 = findViewById(R.id.gear);
                f1.setGear(item4,gear);
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, f1);
                transaction.commit();

        }
    });
```

Your application must create other threads and put long running work on non-UI threads.  There are options on how to accomplish the creation of alternate threads.  You can create and start your own java.lang.Thread.  You can create and start an AsyncTask - Android’s own thread simplification mechanism.  The non-UI thread then handles long running processing – like downloading a file – while the UI thread sticks to displaying the UI and reacting to user events.  Life seems good again.

However, there is a problem in paradise.  Unfortunately, the user interface (UI) cannot be updated by non-UI threads.  For example, after successfully downloading a file, a separate (non-UI) thread can’t show an AlertDialog, update a TextView widget, otherwise make a UI change to indicate the file has been successfully downloaded.  If you attempt to update the UI from a non-UI thread, the application will compile, but you get a CalledFromWrongThreadException thrown from the point your non-UI thread attempts to make the UI change.  As the exception message will inform you, “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.”

for reference, click this link http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-non-ui-to-ui-thread-communications-part-1-of-5/

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged in SO. Please provide an explanation of what his issue is.

Comment: thanks for the reminder. i have added couple of paragraphs from the reference site for the explanation :)

Comment: ok i got it but now the logcat tell me about a null pointer issue of invoking a replace() function probably i must declare the transaction inside the thread .... right ??

Comment: it's hard to tell since the code is incomplete. but yes you can try declaring the transaction inside the ui thread. you can also try to include the codes below in the ui thread

     menu1_Fragment f1 = new menu1_Fragment();
        menu2_Fragment f2 = new menu2_Fragment();
        menu3_Fragment f3 = new menu3_Fragment();